# A temporary placeholder page when server is restarting

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, apache, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

How can I use a temporary placeholder page when the server is restarting? Or what is the common practice to avoid downtime when I have to restart the server?

This is what I use

`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart`

Below is the error message
502 ERROR

> The request could not be satisfied.
>
> *CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection. We
> can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time.
> There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again
> later, or contact the app or website owner.  If you provide content to
> customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and
> help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
> Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup a maintenance page in Amazon CloudFront /S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59331387/how-to-setup-a-maintenance-page-in-amazon-cloudfront-s3)

Comment: @JotaMartos Thanks. I am using lightsail and the steps described aren't applicable to lightsail instances it seems.